# Attempting to INSERT multiple rows into MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I'm trying to insert multiple rows into a MySQL database with the following code, however I keep receiving error 500 (Internal Server Error)...I'm I doing something in correctly here? I'm relatively new to PHP. Thanks

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfOptions; $i++) {
  var $insertOptions;   <<<<<<<< Error here. Should not have 'var' pre-fix

  if ($numbersOrLetters == 0) {

           $optionNumber = $i + 1;
           $insertOptions = "INSERT INTO Survey_results (Survey_authKey, Option_name, Option_value) 
                       VALUES ('$userAuthKey','$optionNumber','0')";
     }
  else {
           $currentValue = $letter[$i];

           $insertOptions = "INSERT INTO Survey_results (Survey_authKey, Option_name, Option_value) 
                       VALUES ('$userAuthKey','$currentValue','0')";
     }

              mysql_query($insertOptions);
  }
```

Comment: "var $insertOptions;" out of place OOP or to much javascript on the brain?

Comment: Please **DO NOT USE** `mysql_query` in any new code. It is extremely dangerous and is very difficult to use safely. [Escape your SQL properly](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have serious problems with your application.

Comment: @Dagon yup, you are exactly right. Way too much javascript :D

Comment: @tadman so how exactly should I change my code? I know you posted that link but it has several options. Is one better than the other / could you provide some sample code if I provide all of the source for this script? Thanks

Comment: @Dagon this was my problem. Thank you very much! Please add as answer

Comment: PDO is the best option, but `mysqli` is a good alternative when PDO is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as requested:

`var $insertOptions;

out of place OOP or to much javascript on the brain?

Answer (score 3):

Add this on top of your script to enable error reporting.

```
 ini_set('display_errors','On');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then you will know what the problem might be.

[PHP Error Reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)